# How to delete Snapshots in oVirt/RHEV

Tags: python, snapshot, rhel

I am writing a script for automatically generating snapshots, which works
pretty well so far.
I would also like to be able to delete snapshots with my script, but it seems like there is no method call documented to do that. I have already found out that with rhev 3.3.0 you have to shutdown VMs to delete them, but still I am not able to delete snapshots.

This is what I have so far:

```
def deleteSnapshot(self):
    VM = self.con.vms.get(self.hostname.replace('.','_'))
    VM_status= VM.status.state 
    if VM_status == 'up':
        self.stopVM()
        time.sleep(10)
    elif VM_status == 'down':
        self.listSnapshotDescription() # This is where the deletion stuff should happen,
```

But I am still not able to find a way to delete these snapshots. I have also searched online to find some usable Redhat documentation on the topic, but haven't been able to find any that is of use.

Can anybody give me a hint or something which points me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

```
>>> mylist = connection.vms.get('host64').snapshots.list()                                                                                    
>>> for snapshot in mylist:                                                                                                                        
...     if snapshot.description == "host64.bla":                                                                               
...         snapshot.delete()
```

and also the VM has to be Shutdown to remove the snapshot

Comment: I have found more short option: snapshots = vm.snapshots.list(description=SNAPSHOT_NAME)